# Permission denied in custom buildpack

Tags: heroku, docker, dokku, buildpack

I am writing a custom buildpack that downloads a file and stores it inside `/var/lib/myfolder`

To do this I first run `mkdir -p /var/lib/myfolder`

But this results in a `Permission Denied` when running the buildpack.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the `/app` folder will be stored at the end of your build, and your buildpack doesn't have sudo access.
You need to store all files inside that folder, and configure your libraries to use dependencies under the right path there.